# about inverse Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform, partial-fractions

Im working out a set of Laplace  inverses, from this one

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}(\frac{-0.2}{s+5}+\frac{0.2s+0.8}{(s+2)^2+1})$$

I understand that the first term is 
$-0.2e^{-5t}$ but the question is the second one, from what Ive been told this is  $$0.2e^{-2t}cost+0.8e^{-2t}sint$$
but in a certain book Ive seen a concept called "generic decaying oscillatory" that shows the inverse Laplace transform of the form 
$$\frac{Bs+C}{(s+a)^2+\omega^2}=e^{-at}(Bcos(\omega t)+\frac{C-aB}{\omega}sin(\omega t))$$
then it would be
$$0.2e^{-2t}cost+0.4e^{-2t}sint$$
How to justify the use of one or another? or what parameter use to choose? 
Thanks

Comment: The inverse Laplace transform result is $\dfrac{1}{5} e^{-2 t} \cos (t) + \dfrac{2}{5} e^{-2 t} \sin (t)$. I would recommend deriving the result from the definition of the inverse Laplace Transform and also using the [*Laplace Transform*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf) table as opposed to any canned results (even if they end up being correct).

Comment: ok thanks, and thanks for the table!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant identity is $L^{-1}(F(s+a))=e^{-at} L^{-1}(F(s))$. So when you go to obtain the cosine term, you want it to look like $\frac{A(s+a)}{(s+a)^2+1}$. To get the "+a" you have to "add and subtract" a term, which changes the coefficient that would be contributing to the sine term. (This is similar to "completing thet square".) This ultimately results in the formula that you had in the middle.